# Run method when (Cucumber) Annotation is called

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, listener, aop

Is there a way in JAVA to listen for a specific annotation that is being called, and run a method before / after the annotation, specifically in a Cucumber / JUnit framework? For example, when the following code is being called due to step in your feature file ("Then something happens"):

```
@Then("something happens")
public void somethingHappens(){
   
  // run code in method

}
```

That before / after the somethingHappens() method is called, another method is called like:

```
public void doSomethingElseBeforeAnnotation(){

// run code in method

}
```

There is the @BeforeStep and @AfterStep in the Cucumber framework, but i want to be able to run the method only at, for example, the "@Then" annotations. So actually, i neeed something like a @BeforeThen :)

Comment: An annotation is not a method or a constructor. It cannot be called.

Comment: Sorry, that could be true. The glue code is responsible for what method will be called I guess, but is that by any means related to the annotation? Or is there another approach that could be taken to a achieve this?